# prime divisor of n less than root n

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Before the question is marked duplicate please read below. Now I've seen many proofs of the theorem:
*If n is a composite integer, then n has a prime divisor less than or equal to* $\sqrt n$

And I've seen many satisfactory proofs. But, the theorem nowhere states explicitly that n cannot have a prime divisor greater than $\sqrt n$, does it? It just says that at least a prime divisor less than $\sqrt n$ must exist, isn't it? And is there a proof that all the prime divisors must strictly be less than $\sqrt n$ ?

Comment: No, there cannot be such a proof. Take $n=15$. This has a prime divisor bigger than $\sqrt{15}$, namely $p=5$.

Comment: Of course.  Take $21= 3*7$.  It has prime divisor $3 < \sqrt {21}$ and it has prime divisor $7 > \sqrt{21}$.

Comment: "But, the theorem nowhere states explicitly that n cannot have a prime divisor greater than n−−√, does it? "  No, and obviously it can.  "It just says that at least a prime divisor less than n−−√ must exist, isn't it?"  Yes, and it says that as an efficiency test.  If you get up to $\sqrt n$ and found no divisors yet, then you *never* will.  Stop.  Its a wast of time to go further. "And is there a proof that all the prime divisors must strictly be less than n−−√ ?" Of course not, because that's obviously not true.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ If $\,n = pq\,$ then $\, p < \sqrt n\iff q > \sqrt n\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "But, the theorem nowhere states explicitly that n cannot have a prime divisor greater than n−−√, does it?"

It doesn't say *anything* about *any* of the other prime divisors.

> "It just says that at least a prime divisor less than n−−√ must exist, isn't it?"

Less than *or equal*.  $25$ does not have a prime divisor *less* than $5$.

> "And is there a proof that all the prime divisors must strictly be less than n−−√ ? "

Well considering that if $n = pq$ and $p < q$ and $p$ and $q$ are prime then $p < \sqrt n  < p$, it is obviously false.

Take $$6 = 2\cdot 3$$
$$2 < \sqrt 6 < 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the factorisation of 36:

\begin{eqnarray*}
36 &=& 1 \times 36 \\
&=& 2 \times 18 \\
&=& 3 \times 12 \\
&=& 4 \times 9 \\
&=& 6 \times 6 \\
&=& 9 \times 4 \\
&=& 12 \times 3 \\
&=& 18 \times 2 \\
&=& 36 \times 1
\end{eqnarray*}

We can write $36 = m \times n$ in many ways, but as $m$ gets bigger, $n$ has to get smaller.

The "middle point" is when $36 = \sqrt{36} \times \sqrt{36} = 6\times 6$.

Lets say we could write $36 = m \times n$ where $m\ge\sqrt{36}$, then that means $n\le\sqrt{36}$.

If both $m$ and $n$ are bigger than $\sqrt{36}=6$, then $36$ would be bigger than $36$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proof for your claim because it is false, consider any number of the form $pq$ with $p<q$ and $p,q$ prime numbers.